# Unable to call static method in cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to display different views on my `Index.cshtml` file in my ASP.NET MVC project. If mobile - one view, if not - another one. In order to do it I am accessing user-agent and check on Android/iOS contains.

```
@using MyProject.Infrastructure.Mobile;
@{
    string userAgent = Context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
    bool isMobile = MobileHelper.IsMobile(userAgent);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Please select your database</title>
</head>
<body>
    @if (isMobile)
    {
      <p>Mobile</p>
    }
    else
    {
      <p>Desktop</p>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

```
namespace MyProject.Infrastructure.Mobile
{
    public class MobileHelper
    {
        public static bool IsMobile(string userAgent)
        {
            return userAgent != null
                ? IsAndroid(userAgent) || IsIos(userAgent)
                : false;
        }

        public static bool IsIos(string userAgent)
        {
            return userAgent != null
                ? userAgent.Contains("iPhone") ||
                  userAgent.Contains("iPad") ||
                  userAgent.Contains("iPod")
                : false;
        }

        public static bool IsAndroid(string userAgent)
        {
            return userAgent != null
                ? userAgent.Contains("Android")
                : false;
        }
    }
}
```

Locally everything works like a charm in both release and debug modes, but when I deploy it to the remote machine, `Index.cshtml` is not displaying at all without any error messages (I see only 500 Internal error). When I comment the line with MobileHelper - everything works. What can cause the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: A `500` could so many things. It would help to get more information, either by [turning off custom error messages](https://stackify.com/web-config-customerrors-asp-net/) (or setting them to remote only) or by using a [trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/logging-tracing) or [failed request logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis).

Comment: Even with turning off custom erors I am unable to see detailed reason why I have 500 error

Comment: Have you tried passing the bool via a view model from the controller?

Comment: Yes, I tried to move the same logic to Controller and pass a model, but the result is the same. By the way, I got the exception. It happens during the execution of app.Use method in startup. I'll update the question